# Select records in Postgres database without any null values

Tags: postgresql

Instead of stating each column name individually, is there a more efficient way to select all rows which do not have any nulls from a table in a Postgres database?

For example, if there are 20 columns in a table, how to avoid typing out each of those columns individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just check the *whole* row:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_table is not null
```

`my_table is not null` is only true if **all** columns in that rows are not null.

Comment: How would you select tables with joins?

Comment: @ShayHa: the same way.

Comment: ```sql select *
from my_table inner join my_other_table
where my_table is not null``` 
Like that?

Comment: Cool, where is this in the postgres documentation? What is this called? Can you apply expressions to whole tables in general, and the results for each column get ANDed together?

Comment: In terms of performance, is it better than checking all columns with different queries? 
Will the cursor parse the whole table or is there some sort of indexation?